# Show that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\bigotimes_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

As the title says, I would like to prove that
$$
\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\bigotimes_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).
$$

(Here $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.)

---

My idea is to show that via generators of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ resp. $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, namely $\Sigma^n$ and $\Sigma$,
$$
(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)=)~~~~\sigma(\Sigma^n)=\sigma\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}pr_i^{-1}(\Sigma)\right)~~~~(=\bigotimes_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})),
$$
whereat
$$
\Sigma:=\left\{(a,b]: a,b\in\mathbb{R},a\leqslant b\right\},~~~\Sigma^n:=\left\{\times_{i=1}^{n}(a_i,b_i]: a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}, a_i\leqslant b_i\right\}
$$
and $pr_i$ is the i-th projection.
(Here f.e. $\sigma(\Sigma^n)$ means the generated $\sigma$-Algebra.)

Let $A\in\Sigma^n$, then $A=\times_{i=1}^{n}(a_i,b_i]$ for $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}, a_i\leqslant b_i, i=1,\ldots,n$. It is
$$
A=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}pr_i^{-1}((a_i,b_i])\in\sigma\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}pr_i^{-1}(\Sigma)\right),
$$
so it is $\sigma(\Sigma^n)\subset\sigma\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}pr_i^{-1}(\Sigma)\right)$.

Now I have some problems with the other inclusion.

Let $A\in\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}pr_i^{-1}(\Sigma)$, then $A=pr_i^{-1}((a,b])$ for some $i\in\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}, a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a\leqslant b$, i.e.
$$
A=\mathbb{R}\times\ldots\times (a,b]\times\ldots\times\mathbb{R}.
$$
Do not know why now it follows $A\in\sigma(\Sigma^n)$.

Comment: You might find that you get more replies if you tell us what $\mathcal{B}$, $\sigma$, $\Sigma$ and $\mathrm{pr}$ mean.

Comment: I think most of it is clear and usual notation: $\sigma(...)$ means generated $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathcal{B}(...)$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra. What $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma^n$ are, is defined: the semi-rings of half-open intervalls, generators of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ resp. $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. And $pr_i$ is the i-th projection.

Comment: Ok, I do, although I cannot understand why it isn't okay to define that in the comment. :-)

Comment: Ok, I edited my question. Hope is better now.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Comment: Hint: Try to prove the general case. It's more general, but it's easier to prove.  "For any second countable tolological space $X$, $\otimes_{i=1}^n \mathscr{B}_X = \mathscr{B}_{X^n}$.

Comment: It's not easier to me, sorry. ;(